# Создание словаря с пустыми значениями

Tags: python, python-2.x

Создается словарь из эксель где ключ это название столбца а значения это номер строки где пустые значения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите почему конструкция ниже добавляет в словарь столбец да же если в нем все строки заполнены т.е не пустые

```
k = {i: df_1[df_1[i].isnull()].index.tolist() for i in df_1.columns}
```

Итог работы вот такой

`{u'Present': [], u'Status_law': [2, 3, 5], u'Useobj': [1, 3, 4, 5]}`

В столбце `Present` все строки заполнены

а должен быть вот такой

`{u'Status_law': [2, 3, 5], u'Useobj': [1, 3, 4, 5]}`

Comment: пример исходного датасета приведите в воспроизводимом виде.

Comment: @strawdog Добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить условие, правда код получится повторяется, но что делать:

```py
k = {i: df_1[df_1[i].isnull()].index.tolist() for i in df_1.columns
     if df_1[df_1[i].isnull()].index.tolist()} # <-- добавлено условие
```

Comment: Внутри скобок обратный слеш для переноса строки не обязательно ставить

Comment: @CrazyElf Почему в качестве условия используется ``df_1[df_1[i].isnull()].index.tolist()``

Comment: @Grechkin26 Можно сделать короче условие, но в данном случае это и есть проверка, что список не пустой.